# clausula IN y una string

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenos días.

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta en MySQL dados los siguientes casos.

Tabla codificaciones

```
id| nombre
------------------------
1 | Correo electronico
2 | Videoconferencia
3 | Foro
4 | Otros
```

Tabla tutorias

```
id|tipo_tutoria
------------
1|1,3
2|2,4
3|2
4|1,2,3
5|
```

Dadas estas tablas, el resultado que me gustaría conseguir es el siguiente:

```
id|tipo_tutoria
------------
1|Correo electronico,Foro
2|Videoconferencia,Otros
3|Videoconferencia
4|Correo electronico,Videoconferencia,Foro
5|
```

Lo máximo que he llegado a conseguir es la siguiente consulta:

> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(nombre)
>   FROM codificaciones
>   WHERE find_in_set (
>       id, (SELECT tipo_tutoria FROM tutorias )
>   );

Obteniendo el siguiente resultado:

```
id|tipo
------------
1|Correo electronico
2|Videoconferencia
3|Videoconferencia
4|Correo electronico
5|
```

Cualquier ayuda lo agradecería mucho.
Un saludo!

Comment: A ver la columna `tipo_tutoria`  ¿de qué tipo de datos es en la tabla?, ¿tienes los datos almacenados así, como los muestras, por ejemplo: `1,3`? Si es así: ¿podrías decir por qué motivo tienes los datos almacenados así? ¿Si hubiera necesidad de modificar las tablas podrías hacerlo o tendrías que someterte al diseño actual?

Comment: Prueba esta consulta:

SELECT tT.id,tC.nombre FROM tablaCodificaciones tC, tablaTutorias tT WHERE tC.id=tT.tipo_tutoria

Comment: Porque se almacenan IDs separados por coma? No es mal diseño eso?

Comment: A.cedano: eso es, lo tengo almacenado asi en la tabla
Diego Anton: El lunes la probaré.
Luis Fernando: Puede ser que sea mal diseño, pero es asi como está en la tabla.
Muchas gracias por contestar

Answer (score -2):

Ya está resuelto. Después de hablar con el analista hemos llegado al punto de modificar el comportamiento de la tabla para que guarde cada id como un registro nuevo, y de ese modo tener un diseño limpio.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda compañeros.

Un saludo

Comment: Hola Cristian. Las respuestas tienen que tener un formato y un contenido de calidad incluso si la pregunta es tuya. Miira [answer] si quieres mejorar esta respuesta añadiendo lo que hiciste para resolverlo. Si no, esto deberia ser un comentario. Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima vez. Consideré una respuesta en vez de un comentario porque realmente cambié la forma en la que ocurría el problema(cada id guardarla como registro nuevo) y se resolvió el problema.
Un saludo.

Comment: No tiene que ser la proxima vez ya que esta pregunta va a perdurar en el sitio. ha de tener la calidad necesaria o si no será convertida en comentario.